# Javascript: collapsible text and link to collapsible text

Tags: javascript

Initially I have applied this code to create a collapsible text. This works without any issues

```js
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;
     
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
```

```css
    .collapsible {
        background-color: #777;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
     
    .active, .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #555;
    }
     
    .collapsible:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
     
    .active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }
     
    .content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
     
     
    <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible ">Unfolds text</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
```

Lately I have been trying to implement another functionality. By placing a text somewhere else in the same page, and clicking on that text, i would like that the website moves to the collapsible text and unfolds it as well.

```
<a href="#collapsible">Link to the collapsible text</a>
```

Is that possible by using the same javascript as specified inside the script-tag? I tried already with an onclick-function (containing the same if-loop inside the javascript) but that did not work.

Thanks for your ideas and collaborations.

Comment: Well, Where is that code you tried ?

Comment: well, onclick="myFunction()" in the a tag, and then the same event as in the if loop plus this.classList.toggle("active");

Comment: *Is that possible* yes it is

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to deploy javascript for this sort of presentational effect.

You can achieve the effect with CSS alone, using the pseudo-element `:target`.

**Working Example:**

```css
section {
height: 60px;
overflow-y: hidden;
transition: height 0.6s linear;
}

section:target {
height: 160px;
}

section h2 {
position: relative;
height: 48px;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0 6px;
line-height: 48px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(95, 95, 95);
cursor: pointer;
}

section:hover h2 {
background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
}

section a h2 {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration: none;
}

section h2::after {
content: '+';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 6px;
font-size: 48px;
}

section:target h2::after {
content: '-';
font-size: 60px;
}

section h2 + div p {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
<a href="#section1"><h2>Unfolds Section 1</h2></a>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Go to <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>. Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Go to <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</section>

<section id="section2">
<a href="#section2"><h2>Unfolds Section 2</h2></a>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Go to <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>. Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Go to <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</section>

<section id="section3">
<a href="#section3"><h2>Unfolds Section 3</h2></a>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Go to <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>. Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Go to <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</section>

<p>Go to <a href="#section1">Section 1</a></p>
<p>Go to <a href="#section2">Section 2</a></p>
<p>Go to <a href="#section3">Section 3</a></p>
```